# Xcode 11 can't create Mac App Distribution Certificate

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 10, the account certificate popup looks like:

[image]

The 2nd and 3rd items are used to build/sign apps for distribution in the Mac App Store.

However, with Xcode 11, it looks like:

[image]

and it can't seem to create a certificate that is titled "3rd Party Mac Developer Application...", although this certificate is recognized and listed in the main list if it was created in Xcode 10. Also notes that the ability to create the iOS certificates is gone.

Furthermore, Xcode 11 shows an odd certificated called "Apple Distribution" but indicates that it contains a missing private key.

Has anyone run into this?

The Xcode 11 release notes talk about the new universal singing certificates but then why does it allow the "Mac Installer Distribution" to be created?

Comment: It’s not a bug, it’s a feature. Apple Development and Distribution certificates now cover both iOS and Mac. Make yourself new ones.

Comment: “ but then why does it allow the "Mac Installer Distribution" to be created?” You are not writing an installer, so don’t worry about it.

Comment: The Installer certificate is needed to sign my app for the Mac App Store (not iOS). To properly submit, it needs to sign the app with the App certificate and the .pkg with the Installer certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the "Mac Installer Distribution" should not be included as an option in Xcode 11 since these have been superseded by "Apple Development" and "Apple Distribution". Thanks Matt!